# How can I pass a parameter from XML Response tag in a new GET XML Request in Soap UI?

Tags: rest, soap, request, response, soapui

I have tried to find a solution in this community in different threads but yet to find one that I am looking for.

I am using SoapUI version 5.3.0 My Application have a couple of RESTful APIs. Initially I am sending json request to a WebService and getting back the following XML Response:

```
<StartDataExtractResult xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AriaTechCore" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <StatusCode>1</StatusCode>
   <StatusText>success</StatusText>
   <RequestNumber>397</RequestNumber>
</StartDataExtractResult>
```

As soon as `RequestNumber` tag is generated. I have to access to 2 more XML EndPoints (where the value of `RequestNumber` is appended) to know the Status as below:

A. `http://quickextract.quickaudit.in/webs/quickextract.svc/GetExtractionDetails/396`

B. 
`http://quickextract.quickaudit.in/webs/quickextract.svc/GetRequestStatus/396`

As of now, I have created the 2 seperateTestSteps for the above mentioned XML Endpoints:

A. `http://quickextract.quickaudit.in/webs/quickextract.svc/GetExtractionDetails/`

B. `http://quickextract.quickaudit.in/webs/quickextract.svc/GetRequestStatus/`

Now I need to append the value within  tag in the GET Request to get back a response from the WebServices.

Update:
I have created a 'Property Transfer' at Testsuite level as "TSreqNum". This 'Property Transfer' is getting updated as per the initial Response. But I am not sure how would I append  "TSreqNum" to construct the complete GET Request as:
`http://quickextract.quickaudit.in/webs/quickextract.svc/GetExtractionDetails/TSreqNum`

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property within the URL of the GET request:

```
http://host:port/path/${#TestSuite#TSreqNum}
```

The URL gets updated with the property value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My Testsuite name being 'QuickExtract-MultipleRequests' I have edited the Resource Field as "/webs/quickextract.svc/GetExtractionDetails/${#QuickExtract-MultipleRequests#TSreqNum}" But I am getting an error as `Endpoint not found` Can you please guide me further?

Comment: The string #TestSuite points to the actual test suite, you shall not replace it with its name.